# roscpp: requesting current queue state of subscriber

Tags: ros, queue, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node, where I would like a subscriber to have a high queue size during initialization of some internal processors (during which my node intentionally lacks calling into ros spinner) to avoid loss of messages in this time but (safely) low queue size when the processor is active, to keep the responsiveness of the processor high.

Is it possible to change the queue size of a subscriber on the fly? Also, can I check how many messages are currently in the queue of a subscriber? I have not found any info on that in the API docu, but maybe someone has an undocumented workaround?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206925/roscpp:-requesting-current-queue-state-of-subscriber/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Changing the queue size dynamically is currently not supported.

None of the information about the current message count in the subscription queue is publically accessible.

If you want to trace the hierarchy: When you `subscribe` on a `NodeHandle` a `Subscription` is added to the `TopicManager`. The subscription will then contain the `SubscriptionQueue` which has the information about the received messages. But most of the members along the line you would be interested in are private.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-04-09**:
Ok, thank you for this information. I think will then stick to an own queue after the callback that I can dynamically resize and set down the subscriber queue to something low.....